# Is rhyming slang used in other parts of the world than London?

Tags: international

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyming_slang):

> Rhyming slang is a form of phrase construction in the English language that is especially prevalent in dialectal English from the East End of London; hence the **alternative name, Cockney rhyming slang.**

But the article also goes on to describe some international versions:

> - In Australian slang, the term for an English person is "pommy", which has been proposed as a rhyme on "pomegranate" rhyming with "immigrant"
> - In Australia and South Africa, the colloquial term "China" is derived from "mate" rhyming with "China plate" (the identical form, heard in expressions like "me old China" is also a long-established Cockney idiom).

I'm not aware of any English rhyming slang Indian speakers use, and I always assumed the practice was limited to London.

**Question**:

What other parts of the world use English rhyming slang, and how prevalent is it in those parts? (By which I mean: would the average speaker know what's being said, and that it's a rhyming slang?)

Comment: Wiki also says: ***Outside England, rhyming slang is used in many English-speaking countries in the Commonwealth of Nations, but is not in general use in the United States***. (Some notable exceptions: "bread" [bread & honey = money], "blow a raspberry" [raspberry tart = fart] and "put up your dukes" [Duke of York = fork, a Cockney slang term for "fist"])....

Comment: ..... ***Rhyming slang is continually evolving*** , and new phrases are introduced all the time. As mentioned, new personalities replace old ones (as in Lionel/Tony Blairs—flares), or pop culture introduces new words—as in "I haven't a Scooby" (from Scooby Doo, the eponymous cartoon dog of the cartoon series) meaning "I haven't a clue".

Comment: @Josh61: Interesting. Thant's enough content for a decent answer.

Comment: This is another interesting issue: What are the origins of Cockney rhyming slang? http://www.quora.com/What-are-the-origins-of-Cockney-rhyming-slang

Comment: "Fa shizzle my nizzle, the big Snoop D-O-double-Gizzle, back up in the hizzle!"

Comment: There is an alternative derivation of "pommy" from P.O.M.E., Prisoner of Mother England. But that feels like a retrospective invention, popular etymology. Just mentioning.

Comment: @Josh. Re the argot used by London criminals, it's a fair supposition that anything known to the likes of us is a whole generation out of date. By definition, the crooks will have invented something new that honest folks don't understand.

Comment: @Josh: To you, "Blowing a raspberry" is a fart? To me it's the noise you make when you put your mouth on the back of your hand and blow. That's a "Bronx cheer" to Americans, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidPugh -        Yes,  ***Thieves' cant or Rogues' cant***   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thieves%27_cant

Comment: This is another interesting link on the subject: ***Let’s take a butcher’s at rhyming slang*** http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/06/rhyming-slang/

Comment: My pleasure, it is a very inyteresting subject but I find it difficult to make a full answer because of its wide and local ramifications.

Comment: @Josh61: Yes, I understand. I'm hoping people who see this will at least provide information about their native lands in the comments.

Comment: @DavidPugh I think _raspberry_ is another word for a Bronx cheer because it sounds like a loud fart, and that came from the rhyming slang.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235715/sounds-like-a-plan-stan/251790

Comment: Hm, seems like rhyming slang is basically either a form of etymology in progress or else [innuendo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innuendo). Consider subtle parodies, especially those set to song.  Especially consider **sexual innuendo**.

Comment: It's used to a limited extent in Scotland. The 'brown bread' for 'dead' sounds different up there, and the football club Hearts are the 'Jam Tarts'.

Comment: It might be hard to differentiate between direct borrowings from Cockney and independent creation in these other varieties.