# "Seems like a plan" vs "sounds like a plan"

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

"Seems like a plan" vs. "sounds like a plan"

Which one is more frequently used and/or correct? Does it depend on whether it is spoken or written?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/235715/14666 “Sounds like a plan (, Stan!)”

Answer (score 1):

“Sounds like a plan” is common. It informally conveys agreement.

While it is more frequently spoken, it can also be written.

The word “seem” can be used to make a statement less forceful. So if the context is agreeing or disagreeing with a proposal, “seems like a plan” implies hesitance when compared with “sounds like a plan”.

Comment: Hello, Mark, and welcome to English Language & Usage. But to quote  @Sven Yargs: 'Your answer seems to be heavily weighted toward personal opinion as opposed to objective analysis—but this site especially prizes answers that have an identifiable basis in verifiable fact rather than just opinion. Please consider strengthening your answer by citing some independent authority that draws the same general conclusion that you do with regard to usage of “Seems like a plan” vs “sounds like a plan”. Thanks.!'

Comment: Indeed, "seems like a plan" invites "...but"

Comment: If you have the comment privilege, you can use that, else you may need to wait till you earn the privilege.